# Optionals in Swift - not assigning default value for optionals

Tags: swift

```
let company : String? // = nil

if company == nil {
   var newCompany = company ?? "apple"
}
```

In this code identifier company we need to assign as
`let company : String?  = nil`
 but apple documentation is telling that no need for assigning  nil value

Comment: `let company: String? = Optional.none
print(company == nil) //true`

Answer (score 2):

You declared **a constant without a value** and **without an initializer** that can change it, which is nonsensical. The compiler, therefore, warns you that you should initialize the constant.

Change `let` to `var` and your code will work fine.